# Submitting iron-form with Enter doesn't work when focus is in paper-input

Tags: polymer

Consider following view:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-form/iron-form.html">

<dom-module id="my-view1">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;

        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    <div class="card">
      <div class="circle">1</div>
      <h1>View One</h1>

      <iron-form id="loginForm">
          <form action="/" method="POST">
              <label>From here it works:</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
              <paper-input id="uid" label="Username" type="text" required auto-validate></paper-input>
              <paper-input id="pwd" label="Password" type="password" required auto-validate></paper-input>
              <button type="submit" class="no-style">Submit</button>
          </form>
      </iron-form>
    </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    class MyView1 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'my-view1'; }
    }

    window.customElements.define(MyView1.is, MyView1);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

When focus is in `<input>` hitting Enter will submit the form. When the focus is in `<paper-input>` it will not.

This used to work fine in Polymer 1.

Has something changed?

Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be related https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-form/issues/189

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile, while this browser specific bug is being fixed, you can add an onkeyup event and call a method that sends the form if the user hits enter.

```
<paper-input on-keyup="postForm" label="username" value="{{username::input}}">
```

And the function should look something like....

```
postform: function(event) {
  var enter = 13;

  if (event.keyCode === enter) {
    // code to post form
  }
}
```